# Java development environment

Tags: windows, java, ide

I am totally new to this whole programming stuff. So I started with simple websites by using Atom. But now I want to do something with Java for a Raspberry Pi project.

I already tried it in Atom but it doesn´t really work well.

So I need a Java development environment which runs on Windows 10 and doesn´t cost that much or even doesn´t cost anything.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Comment: Yes, please give us some requirements, you have the start of a decent question, just needs some more info for us to work with.

Comment: Are you deploying to a Raspberry Pi or developing on a Pi? If developing on a more capable machine, you have more choices.

Comment: Since the Windows tag is used, geus the IDE is for Windows. For Java would recomend Eclipse it´s crosplatform and free.

Answer (score 5):

## JDK

[Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28software_platform%29) is a [set of specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/), for [the language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29) and for the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine).

To do your programming, you need an implementation of those specs. That implementation is known as a [Java Development Kit (JDK)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit).

You have a choice of several vendors who provide binaries or installers for various host hardware and operating systems. Those vendors include, off the top of my head: Azul Systems, Amazon, Microsoft, Oracle, Adoptium (formerly AdoptOpenJDK), SAP, BellSoft, Red Hat/IBM, Pivotal, *Ports and Packages* for BSD, *apt* for Linux, and more. For a beginner just getting started, I would suggest Adoptium as a first stop in shopping.

Some JDK products are available free of cost. Some require a fee that usually includes a support plan. Be sure to understand the terms of any software product before downloading.

Nearly all of these vendors’ JDK products are based largely, if not entirely, on the codebase of the [*OpenJDK*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project, a group effort led by Oracle along with IBM, Apple, and others.

For more info, read [*Java Is Still Free*](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-3-0-0-ocrt-2021-bca75c88d23b).

## Text-editor

Getting started, you can use most any [text editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_editor). And obtain a [Java Development Kit (JDK)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) from any of [several vendors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58829680/642706).

Later versions of Java added the convenience of not having to explicitly compile. You can simply run a `.java` source file using `java your-file-name-here.java`, and the compiler (`javac` tool) will automatically be invoked, then your compiled `.class` is executed (`java` tool).

## *JShell* (a REPL)

Later versions of Java add the [read–eval–print loop (REPL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) facility. You can type one line at a time, incrementally being compiled and executed as you go.

This tool is known as [*JShell*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JShell). Bundled with Java 9 and later. Defined in [*JEP 222: jshell: The Java Shell (Read-Eval-Print Loop)*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/222).

JShell is good for learning and experimenting, but not for building a serious app.

## BlueJ

[image: product logo for BlueJ IDE]

[*BlueJ*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlueJ) is an open-source free-of-cost IDE **designed for students learning Java**. This tool eliminates much of the overwhelming complexity of the commercial IDEs discussed below.

## IDEs

[image]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d5/IntelliJ_IDEA_Logo.svg/128px-IntelliJ_IDEA_Logo.svg.png))</sub>

[image]  
[image]

The three main popular [integrated development environment (IDE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) products are:

- [*IntelliJ*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) by [JetBrains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains) (Community edition is free-of-cost)
- [*NetBeans*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) by [Apache Software Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Software_Foundation)
- [*Eclipse*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) by [Eclipse Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_Foundation)

All of these run on [Microsoft Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows) as well as macOS, Linux, etc.

All of these are:

- Free-of-cost.
- Open-source
- Actively developed.
- Extremely powerful and very useful.
- Laden with bolted-on features, awkwardly designed, and come with a learning curve.

I’ve delivered software using each of them. Each has their own fanbase. NetBeans was quite useful to me when I was starting out. Nowadays I use IntelliJ, Ultimate Edition, a commercial paid product that adds certain features on top of their free-of-cost Community Edition product. Some folks swear by Eclipse, though I found it clunky in a designed-by-committee sort of way. You can be successful with any one of these three.

A fourth option is [*JDeveloper*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDeveloper) by Oracle, free-of-cost but proprietary (closed-source). I have not tried it, nor have I spoken with anyone using it. So I have no opinion.

You’ve not given enough criteria to make a further recommendation.

## Build-automation & dependency-management

By the way, most of the IDEs support projects driven by [*Apache Maven*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven), [*Apache Ivy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ivy), or [Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle), besides their own project-definition-and-build technology. These tools provide [build-automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) and [dependency-management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_%28project_management%29) services.

*Maven* is most common. Eventually, you will likely want to put some time into learning the basics of Maven and its POM files.

Comment: @karel No, I don't think JShell exactly answers your Question there, but I added a comment with links as an FYI to other readers.

Answer (score -2):

You can join udemy academy, there are lot of java best tutorials on-boarded.

You’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better.

Comment: OP asked for an IDE and not resources for learning...